# Google Tag Manager v4 Android App Testing

Tags: android, testing, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, charles-proxy

I have implemented Google Tag Manager version 4 on my android app. Now the developer has shared the app with me for testing. I have tried using fiddler / charles mitm proxy for testing google analytics calls however i am not able to see any calls going to any google analytics server. However interestingly i can see data in real time reports.

Please let me know how can we get the app tested after getting GTMv4 implementation.

Thanks

Comment: If you can see data in the real time reports then its working,  data wont show up in the standard reports for 24 hours.

Comment: Real time data only show data for certain limited dimensions. We have done custom tracking and want to check whether right values are getting set for various screens and events.
Also we want to test it in real time and dont want to wait for 24 hours to check data.
Similar to what we can do on Web with debuggers like observepoint etc.

Comment: I appreciate that you don't want to wait 24 hours to check the data but that's the way it is.   Data doesn't appear in he standard reports for 24 hours.

Comment: isnt there a way in which we can check data flowing from mobile app to google analytics servers.
Similar to Adobe Analytics or Apps Flyer etc.

Comment: The only way to see data that is being sent right now to Google Analytics is to check the real time reports.  The real time reports are very limited in what you can see. It is best to wait 24 hours to see the full data.

Comment: thats really sad. :(. Because no one can do proper testing in that way. 
As this app is being used by other testers as well no way to differentiate our testing data from other testing data.

Comment: Google analytics data is meant to be non user specific.  You shouldn't be able to track individual users this is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The Real-time Google analytics reports shows a limited amount of information with relation to what is happening on your site right now.

The standard reports have much more information but it takes 24 - 48 hours for the data to be processed in the background by Google.   There is nothing you can do to change this even using the Google Analytics API wont show you any more data.

You will need to wait at least 24 hours to check that your data has been sent to Google analytics and processed correctly.